# Using environment variable in react-native swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am working on React-Native App and want to configure env variables which I can share with iOS app and Android.

The documentation requires me to add this line in AppDelegate.m

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"Azzz8"];`
```

Here `Azzz8` would be my api key. Now I want to pass this to be in an environment file and pass it from there (to ios and android). Any idea how I can do it?

This is how my code for AppDelegate.m kinda looks like

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  /* Firebasee App Config */
  [FIRApp configure];
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"1234"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) library. It allows you to access environment variables defined in a *.env* file in the native portion, as well as the JavaScript portion of the app.